# Docker: SLF4J-Error with Docker + Confluence-Server + MySQL - "docker run" works, "docker-compose up" not

Tags: mysql, docker, tomcat, docker-compose, confluence

I'm trying to run confluence with mysql using Docker Desktop on Windows 10 in a multi-container application using a `docker-compose.yml` file like this:

```
services: 
  confluence:
    image: atlassian/confluence-server:7.4.6
    build: ./confluence
    container_name: confluence
    hostname: confluence
    volumes: 
      - ./confluence/data/confluence:/var/atlassian/application-data/confluence   # for the confluence.cfg.xml
      - ./confluence/lib:/opt/atlassian/confluence/confluence/WEB-INF/lib   # for the mysql driver jar-file
    ports:
      - 8090:8090
      - 8091:8091

  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    build: ./mysql
    container_name: mysql
    hostname: mysql
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    environment: 
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
    command: [mysqld, --character-set-server=utf8, --collation-server=utf8_bin, --default-storage-engine=INNODB, --max_allowed_packet=256M, --innodb_log_file_size=2GB, --transaction-isolation=READ-COMMITTED, --binlog_format=row]
```

However when I run this with `docker-compose up --build --force-recreate` I get

> INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.33]
> confluence    | **Handler error**
> confluence    | **java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.bridge.SLF4JBridgeHandler**
> confluence    |         at ... at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
> confluence    |         at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
> confluence    | SEVERE [Catalina-utility-1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
> confluence    | SEVERE [Catalina-utility-1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Context [] startup failed due to previous errors
> confluence    | INFO [Catalina-utility-2] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
> confluence    | SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
> confluence    | SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
> confluence    | SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.

When I run `docker run -v d:/docker/conf-mysql/confluence/data/confluence:/var/atlassian/application-data/confluence --name="confluence" -p 8090:8090 -p 8091:8091 atlassian/confluence-server:7.4.6` I get

> INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.33]
> INFO [Catalina-utility-2] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
> SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
> SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
> SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.

So: In both cases SLF4J falls back to NOP-mode but when I use `docker-compose up` I get a severe error and a 404 on localhost:8090 because Tomcat could not load SLF4J and when I use `docker run` confluence starts up on the URI, but then has no DBMS to connect to.

Any ideas? Please help! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, that was easy:
I simply had to remove the line

- ./confluence/lib:/opt/atlassian/confluence/confluence/WEB-INF/lib

My initial understanding was that files bound to the container like that, would be added to and accessible through the folder ( like a link ).
Obviously "volumes" reroutes the whole path to the host and if there are files in the container's folder, they are not accessible any more, while the volume is bound to the container.

Hope this helps someone! :-)